# Sequelize Base Error : null

Tags: node.js, express

I am wondering the nature of this error? Any idea debugging will be much appreciated!

```
Unhandled rejection SequelizeBaseError: null
    at /Users/master/node_modules/sequelize/lib/instance-validator.js:74:14
    at tryCatcher (/Users/master/node_modules/bluebird/js/release/util.js:16:23)
    at Promise._settlePromiseFromHandler (.
```

I think I am passing in all the required fields in something like the following:

```
app.post("/api/posts", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  db.Post.create({
    image: req.body.image,
    caption: req.body.caption,
    tags: req.body.tags
  }).then(function(dbPost) {
    res.redirect('/');
    console.log("posted!")
  });
});
```

checking allowNotNull, datatype ok, and so forth

Here is my model:

```
var Post = sequelize.define("Post", {
   caption: {
      type: DataTypes.TEXT,
      allowNull: false,
      validate: {
        len: [1]
      }
   },
   likes: {
     type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
     defaultValue: 0
   },
   image: {
     type: DataTypes.STRING,
     allowNull: false
   },
   tags: {
     type: DataTypes.STRING
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a typical `Unhandled Promise Rejection Error`, and is due to you not having a `.catch` after your `.then`:

```
app.post("/api/posts", function(req, res) {
  console.log(req.body);
  db.Post.create({
    image: req.body.image,
    caption: req.body.caption,
    tags: req.body.tags
  }).then(function(dbPost) {
    res.redirect('/');
    console.log("posted!")
  }).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle the error here
    console.error(error);
  });
```

There is an error in your code, but due to the asynchronous nature of Promises and that you're not catching the error you don't actually get to know what it is.

Comment: You nailed for me! Highly appreciated your time!

Comment: Add calling `next` function in `catch` block: `catch (err) { ... next(err) }`, because in your example server won't send response in the case of error.

Comment: @alexmac hence why I added the comment `// Handle the error here`. Since I don't know how Moh K wants to handle his errors I leave that up to him to decide.